# UIView frame is set wrongly, view got {nan, nan} origin.

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

This is part of my code.

```
NSLog(@"fr: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame_)); NSLog(@"org: %@",
NSStringFromCGPoint(frame_.origin)); //    cell.frame = frame_; [cell
setFrame: frame_];

NSLog(@"c: %@", cell); NSLog(@"c frame: %@",
NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
```

And the printouts are surprising. Anyone got any idea on this? help and thanks.

```
[657:707] fr: {{350, 600}, {175, 300}}
[657:707] org: {350, 600}
[657:707] c: <JXUIGridViewCell: 0xf62d3c0; frame = (nan nan; 175 300); tag = 4010; animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x15b4a0>; bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x15b540>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0xf62d400>>
[657:707] c frame: {{nan, nan}, {175, 300}}
```

Comment: You didn't say how you get **frame_**. Can you show that code?

Comment: I do not remembeer how to get `frame_`. howevery the NSLog-printout works to tell what is in the `frame_`. right ?

Comment: Could you solve that problem? I currently have the same and have no clue of what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually looking for an answer for this very problem as well. But came up short. 
But it turns out, that if you at any point set the origin of a view to nan, then it will stick. Thus it can never be changed again.
Solution: Never set origin of view to nan.